# Primefaces default css not work with Glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: primefaces, glassfish-4.1, netbeans-8.1

When creating a template and it automatically creates `css` files and after create `jsp` using `template`,

- In glassfish 4.0 it works [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRz7a.png). But Glassfish 4.1.1 `css` doesn't work. It looks like plain text. [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2wrR.png)

Comment: You will need to add a lot more detail to your question for anyone to have a hope of answering.

Comment: @Mike : updated with images.

Comment: What did you all inspect? I assume you as a developer are capable of more than just taking screenshots. And how is it netbeans related? Does it work in Eclipse?

Comment: @Kukeltje didn't try with eclipse. this is so urgent. thats i asked here.

Comment: If it is so urgent, al the more reason to ask good questions like [ask] and investigate as much as possible upfront. Questions like this cannot be answered without asking a lot of questions for clarification first. That would mean delay for you an a kind of waste of our effective time. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the advice. still im new to here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>
        <title>Facelets Template</title>
    </h:head>
```

Instead of 
`<h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>` 
use 
`<link href="./../resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Comment: I  cannot imagine this makes a difference in the two GF versions. Are you sure?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes. I tried with both. This is the only issue. After input `css` without tag library, that's working.